# Pass a value to an OrderBy or OrderByDescending statement in Linq?

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Dynamic LINQ OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby)

How can I pass a value to an OrderBy or OrderByDescending statement in Linq? I am trying to get the property name dynamically:

```
x.GetType().GetProperty(sortField)
```

Which doesnt seem to work. Any Ideas?

```
private void DynamicSort(ref List<Quote> myQuotes, String sortField, String direction)
{         
        if(direction == "ASC"){
            this.grdViewDrafts.DataSource = myQuotes.OrderBy(x =>  x.GetType().GetProperty(sortField)).ToList();
        }else{
            this.grdViewDrafts.DataSource = myQuotes.OrderByDescending(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sortField)).ToList();
        }

}
```

Solution:

```
this.grdViewDrafts.DataSource =  myQuotes.OrderBy(x => x.GetType().GetProperty(sortField).GetValue(x, null)).ToList();
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41244/dynamic-linq-orderby

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem in your code is that you just get `PropertyInfo` object but not the property value itself. To get property value you have to call `GetValue()` method of the `PropertyInfo` object.

Comment: this method made the query performed very slow if you have more records.

Comment: @Libertad yes, reflection is slow. You’d best to avoid it unless required and cache PropertyInfo/MethodInfo/etc. methods if possible